# How to add a second tooltip to highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to add an external popover to highcharts. I'm currently looking at using [WebUI Popover](http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/demo/)

So the standard highcharts popover displays the standard data, however, I would like to use WebUI Popover to display some data to explain a specific column, which can be fetched from the DB.

The actual fetching of data etc is fine, but I can't figure out how to display a specific popover for a column

The way WebUI Popover works is that it requires some HTML identifier to know where to show the popover:

```
$(#identifier).webuiPopover({"content"})
```

I cant find any identifier to use to link the popover to each column:

```
<g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(55,48) scale(1 1)" style="" clip-path="url(#highcharts-3)">
    <rect x="63.5" y="33.5" width="119" height="162" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="rgb(124, 181, 236)" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="1" data-target="webuiPopover0"></rect>
    <rect x="309.5" y="98.5" width="119" height="97" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="rgb(124, 181, 236)" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="1"></rect>
    <rect x="555.5" y="65.5" width="119" height="130" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="rgb(124, 181, 236)" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="1"></rect>
</g>
```

So I want to show a popover for each coloumn (rect), but I really don't know how. I've tried:

```
var thePoint = "rect[x='" + 63.5 + "'][y='" + 33.5 + "']"; 
$(thePoint).webuiPopover(...)
```

This works to some extent, but obviously I've hard coded the 63,5 and 33,5. I've tried everything to dynamically get the x and y values, but I can never get those exact numbers.

Any other suggestions? Maybe if someone could explain how the built in popover gets the position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this demo of clickable points: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

It uses `Highslide`.

If you want to use `WebUI Popover`, then you can find columns' rectangles and add popups. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/j57me5w1/

Looks like popups will start from top left corner.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        }]
    });

    var columns = $('.highcharts-tracker > rect');
    $.each(columns, function (i, c) {
        $(c).webuiPopover({
            title: 'test',
            content: '<div id="popup">popup content</div>',
            closeable: true,
            arrow: true,
            placement: 'auto'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Kacper! I think this should help a lot...Could you please explain the use of "i" and "c" in the function? As well as why you can use "c" as an identifier?

Comment: Also @Kacper , how can I manipulate your code to work on mouseOver of a column, instead of a click?

Comment: @Palindrome "i" - index, "c" - column (value). More about jQuery's each: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ I use "c" as an identifier for webuiPopover to work - it is jQuery's function. You wanted popup from rect, so "c" is pointing to it. To make webuiPopover work on hover set in its options `trigger: 'hover'`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/j57me5w1/1/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!